# What is the use of any_instance method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see the following line in one of the test files in rails. It has a method called as `any_instance`. What is its use? Can someone please explain

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(Person.site.host, Person.site.port)
ActiveResource::Connection.any_instance.expects(:http).returns(http)
http.expects(:request).returns(ActiveResource::Response.new(""))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`any_instance`](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Class.html#M000001) is a [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) method. From the doc page:

> Returns a mock object which will detect calls to any instance of this class.
>
> ```
> Product.any_instance.stubs(:save).returns(false)
> product_1 = Product.new
> assert_equal false, product_1.save
> product_2 = Product.new
> assert_equal false, product_2.save
> ```

Comment: Mocha is a stubbing and mocking framework, which is used in unit testing to simulate interacting with objects in a controlled manner. In the case of your code, a call to `ActiveResource::Connection#http` for any `ActiveResource::Connection` object accessed during the unit test will return the `http` object created in the first line.